# An inequality with a function twice differentiable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Function f: $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is of Class $C^2$, Suppose $f(0)=1/2$, $f'(0)=1$, $|f''(x)| \le 1 $ $\forall x \in[-1,1]$. We also have $|f(c+k)-f(c)-f'(c)k|\le \frac{k^2}{2}$, for $c, c+k \in [-1,1]$.
Now, set $c_0=0, k_0=-f(c_0)/f'(c_0)=-1/2, c_1=c_0+k_0$. Show that $f'(c_1)\ge f'(c_0)-|k_0|$

Class $C^2$ means twice differentiable. By setting $c_1=c_0+k_0$, I only get $|f(c_1)|\le \frac {k^2}{2}$, and also $f'(c_0)-|k_0|=1/2$ but stuck to get the above inequality. Please avoid integration steps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which is the role here of $c_n,k_n$ for $n\ge2$?

Comment: @mrprottolo It might not be a necessary property to solve the problem, because the problem is a part of bigger question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $|f''(x)|\le 1$ in $[-1,1]$ you have that
$$\Big|\frac{f'(x+h)-f'(x)}{h}\Big|\le1$$
for every $x,x+h \in [-1,1]$. Take $x=c_0,h=k_0$ and you get the inequality.

Comment: Just to make sure, is it because $|f''(x)|=\lim_{h \to 0} |\frac {f'(x+h)-f'(x)}{h}|\le 1$, then you get $|\frac {f'(x+h)-f'(x)}{h}|\le 1$ ?

Comment: The best way to see it it's the mean value theorem.

Comment: By MVT, I get $|f'(c_0)-f'(c_1)|\le |k_0|$, how do I show $f'(c_0) \ge f'(c_1)$?

Comment: By MVT you get $\frac{f'(x+h)-f'(x)}{h}=f''(c)$ for some $c \in (x,x+h)$, but you know that $|f''(c)|\le1$ from the hypothesis. So you get $|\frac{f'(x+h)-f'(x)}{h}|\le1$

Comment: From your result of $|\frac {f'(x+h)-f'(x)}{h}|\le 1$, and take $x=c_0, h=k_0$, I could get $|f'(c_1)-f'(c_0)|\le |k_0|$. But since the question is asking for $f'(c_1)\ge f'(c_0)-|k_0|$, I need to show $|f'(c_1)-f'(c_0)| = f'(c_0)-f'(c_1) \le |k_0|$ , that is $f'(c_0)\ge f'(c_1)$, but I'm not sure how to show $f'(c_0)\ge f'(c_1)$.

Comment: Of course $f'(c_0)-f'(c_1)\le|f'(c_1)-f'(c_0)|\le|h_0|$

Comment: It may seem trivial, but why is $f'(c_0)-f'(c_1)\le |f'(c_1)-f'(c_0)|$?

Comment: Because every number is less or equal than its modulus: $x\le|x|=|-x|$.